# Arranging elements within groups in a dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am stuck with this problem,someone help me out in this.
My problem is I have a dataframe named "df" which is like this,

```
 City              Complaint              Elapsed_Time
ARVERNE        Illegal Fireworks        0 days 00:19:00 
RIDGEWOOD      Homeless Encampment      1 days 04:39:00
ARVERNE        Homeless Encampment      0 days 02:37:00
RIDGEWOOD      Drinking                 0 days 00:14:19
```

I want the answer to be

```
ARVERNE        Illegal Fireworks        0 days 00:19:00
               Homeless Encampment      0 days 02:37:00
RIDGEWOOD      Drinking                 0 days 00:14:19
               Homeless Encampment      1 days 04:39:00
```

That is i want order the "complaint" types based on "elapsed_time" and group them according to "cities".
I currently tried with this code,

```
df=df.sort_values('Elapsed_Time').groupby(['City','Complaint'])
```

and i used this code too,

```
df=df.sort_values('Elapsed_Time').groupby(['City'])
```

And used sort_values and groupby functions in separate codes to but for all these Code I am getting the result as,

```
RIDGEWOOD      Drinking                 0 days 00:14:19
ARVERNE        Illegal Fireworks        0 days 00:19:00
ARVERNE        Homeless Encampment      0 days 02:37:00
RIDGEWOOD      Homeless Encampment      1 days 04:39:00
```

So how can solve this problem???

Comment: Sorry, actually I wanted to show the dataframe in table form but it happened to like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To order `Complaint` within each `City` group by `Elapsed_Time`, simply order the whole data-frame by `City` & `Elapsed_Time`

To visualize the data such that the `City` is not repeated in each row, create a multi index with `City` & `Complaint`

putting it all together:

```
df.sort_values(['City', 'Elapsed_Time']).set_index(['City', 'Complaint'])

# outputs:

                                  Elapsed_Time
City      Complaint                           
ARVERNE   Illegal Fireworks    0 days 00:19:00
          Homeless Encampment  0 days 02:37:00
RIDGEWOOD Drinking             0 days 00:14:19
          Homeless Encampment  1 days 04:39:00
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it worked. Even I tried with set_index but i used it like, set_index(['City']) but didn't used 'Complaint'. Thank you